# check string character and length

Tags: c++, std, eof

This code suppose to accept numbers only and numbers must be exactly 12 numbers. The first is working but the latter is not. User enter 13 numbers but no error is display.

```
 std::string line;
    double d;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        if (ss >> d || line.size() == 12)
        {
            if (ss.eof())
            {   // Success
                break;
            }
        }

        std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
    }
```

Please can somebody help me with this to get it work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try **and** instead of **or**:

```
if (ss >> d && line.size() == 12)
```

Comment: What is the return value of `ss >> d`? I would guess `ss` for chaining, but then this wouldn't work.

Comment: You're correct, `ss >> d` returns `ss`.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yes, `ss >> d` returns `ss` which could be [converted to `bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). The conversion operator is inherited from `std::basic_ios`.

Comment: I haven't thought of overloading the `(bool)` operator 0_o. In normal languages, Objects are always true ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak, a very convenient and nice feature of C++ IMO. If an object's inner states state it is in a "broken/bad" state, then it should evaluate to false when used in a boolean condition. I think it makes more sense than having it always eval to true. :)

Comment: @prazuber can you explain to me what this thing really do `if (ss.eof())
            {   // Success
                break;
            }` I lookup the tutorial but I still couldn't understand how assigning `string ss` to `double d` could detect whether it's string or numbers. Appreciate your reply. Thank you.

Comment: @sg552 You don't assign `ss` to `double d`, you attempt to convert the data in _stringstream_ to _double_. This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ils6dyVycd0&feature=player_embedded) covers the basics of `stringstream`. If you want more detailed look on I/O in general, I suggest [this book](http://www.angelikalanger.com/iostreams.html).